# SQL Oracle how to extract xml tag content in a blob column

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g

There is an xml that is in a column of type BLOB (in oracle) and I need to access a certain tag from that xml. Until then I can retrieve the column this way:

```
SELECT TRIM(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(my_column_blob, 1024))) as tag_name_xml
FROM my_table
```

the return is like this:
[image]

Here I leave part of the xml content:
[image]

How do I return the value/content of the cUF or cCT tag?
I would like the help of people with more knowledge, please.

the proposed solutions are very elegant, but for my case what would it be like to access with this xml structure to access the contents of the cUF tag?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cteProc xmlns="http://www.example.com" version="3.00">
   <CTe>
      <infCte version="3.00">
         <ide>
            <cUF>15</cUF>
         </ide>
      </infCte>
   </CTe>
</cteProc>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `XMLTYPE` and `XMLTABLE`:

```sql
SELECT x.c
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         '/a/b/c'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(t.value, 1)
         COLUMNS
           c VARCHAR2(200) PATH './text()'
       ) x;
```

Or `XMLQUERY`:

```sql
SELECT XMLQUERY('/a/b/c/text()' PASSING XMLTYPE(value, 1) RETURNING CONTENT) AS c
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value BLOB);

INSERT INTO table_name (value)
VALUES ( UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW( '<a><b><c>something</c></b></a>' ) );
```

Both output:

> | C |
> | --- |
> | something |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ecde490acd691c1b661a87ee38f5baab)*

Comment: I understand that xml data from the question are somewhere within some binaries  in the BLOB in which case this will not work without conversion to CLOB (or varchar ...). It is, offcourse, the ok solution for clean xml content.

Comment: @dr The question does not mention binary data within the `BLOB`, the OP only wants to extract certain tags. Even if there is binary data then it is usually stored as Base64 within the XML and that is still only text data and can retrieved in exactly the same manner as this answer (possibly changing `VARCHAR2` to `CLOB`) and then subsequently converted back to a `BLOB`.

Comment: I agree, if there are clean xml formated characters. It is just that pictures above showing some binaries at the begining of a row, before xml. There is also a possibility thrre are more of them in the BLOB, otherways I would expect the data to be stored in a CLOB type. Wouldn't you too?

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert your BLOB data into CLOB type, and then extract the tags you need. Here are two functions that will, hopefully, solve your problem:

```sql
FUNCTION BLOB2CLOB(mBLOB IN BLOB) 
    RETURN CLOB IS
BEGIN
    Declare
        mCLOB   CLOB;
        mDestOffSet     INTEGER;
        mSrcOffSet      INTEGER;
        mBLOBCSID       INTEGER;
        mLangCntx       INTEGER;
        mWarn           INTEGER;
    Begin
        mDestOffSet := 1;
        mSrcOffSet := 1;
        mBLOBCSID := 0;
        mLangCntx := 0;
        mWarn := 0;
        DBMS_LOB.CreateTemporary(mCLOB, TRUE);
        DBMS_LOB.ConvertToClob(mCLOB, mBLOB, DBMS_LOB.GetLength(mBLOB), mDestOffSet, mSrcOffSet, mBLOBCSID, mLangCntx, mWarn);
        RETURN(mCLOB);
    End;
END BLOB2CLOB;
--
FUNCTION Get_SOAP_PartCLOB(mCLOB IN CLOB, mTag IN VARCHAR2) RETURN CLOB 
  IS
BEGIN
    Declare
        wrkCLOB         CLOB;
    myStart       NUMBER(10) := 0;
    myEnd         NUMBER(10) := 0;
    myLength      NUMBER(10) := 0;
    toErase       NUMBER(10) := 0;
    Begin
    DBMS_LOB.CreateTemporary(wrkCLOB, True);
    DBMS_LOB.COPY(wrkCLOB, mCLOB, DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(mCLOB));
    --
    myStart := DBMS_LOB.InStr(wrkCLOB, mTag, 1, 1) + Length(mTag) - 1;
    myEnd := DBMS_LOB.InStr(wrkCLOB, SubStr(mTag, 1, 1) || '/' || SubStr(mTag, 2));
    myLength := DBMS_LOB.GetLength(wrkCLOB);
    
    DBMS_LOB.ERASE(wrkCLOB, myStart, 1);
    toErase := myLength - myEnd + 1;

    DBMS_LOB.ERASE(wrkCLOB, toErase, myEnd);
    
    wrkCLOB := REPLACE(wrkCLOB, ' ', '');

        RETURN(wrkCLOB);
    End;
END Get_SOAP_PartCLOB;
```

You can use it like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    Get_SOAP_PartCLOB(BLOB2CLOB(YOUR_BLOB_COL), 'your_tag_in_clob') as "TAG_COL_ALIAS"
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE
```

I use the second function Get_SOAP_PartCLOB() to get some pretty big B64 data out of the soap envelope response from certain web services. That's why the return type is CLOB. You can cast the returned value to something else or make your own adjustments to the function.